# combinations within set spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using java spark 2.3.1.
I need to get word pairs out of a set of words, and I ran out of ideas.I'm trying to use java spark api to achieve the best performance possible.

I have the following dataset:

```
+----------------------+
|words                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+----------------------+
|[a, b, c, d]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
|[m, a, b]         
+----------------------+
```

What I'd like to achieve is:

```
+------+------+
|word a|word b|
+------+------+
|     a|     b|
|     a|     c|
|     a|     d|
|     b|     c|
|     b|     d|
|     c|     d|
|     m|     a|
|     m|     b|
|     a|     b|
+--------------+
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Your dataset always has just two rows?

Comment: no, there are lots of rows

Comment: Are you going to always apply this to two rows only? Also, what is the typical size of the word sets? What is your ultimate goal?